# How do i create multiple instances with Terraform

Tags: terraform, vsphere, terraform-provider-vsphere

I want to generate multiple instances of a resource with Terraform.
The following script works great for one instance. Unfortunately, the created VM is simply overwritten with different parameters when a new VM is created.
As far as I know, the Terraform function `for_each` cannot be used in the `data` blocks.

How do I manage to create multiple instances with different parameters?
Unfortunately, my knowledge of Terraform is very limited. Therefore I am grateful for any help.

**Terraform skript:**

```
# Provider
provider "vsphere" {
  user                 = var.vsphere_user
  password             = var.vsphere_password
  vsphere_server       = var.vsphere_server
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

# Datacenter
data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = var.vsphere_datacenter
}

# Datastore
data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = var.vsphere_datastore
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

# Cluster
data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = var.vsphere_compute_cluster
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

# Network
data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = var.vsphere_network
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

# Template
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name          = var.vsphere_virtual_machine_template
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

# Import the random password provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    random = {
      source = "hashicorp/random"
    }
  }
}

# Create a new random password
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length           = 25
  upper            = true
  lower            = true
  number           = true
  special          = true
  min_upper        = 2
  min_lower        = 2
  min_numeric      = 2
  min_special      = 1
  override_special = "!@#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
}

# Virtual Machine Resource
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "server-instance" {
  # System
  firmware  = "efi"
  guest_id  = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id
  scsi_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type

  # VM-Name
  name             = var.system_name
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id

  # CPU
  num_cpus               = var.system_cores
  num_cores_per_socket   = var.system_cores_per_socket
  cpu_hot_add_enabled    = true
  cpu_hot_remove_enabled = true

  # Memory
  memory                 = var.system_memory
  memory_hot_add_enabled = true

  # Network
  network_interface {
    network_id   = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    adapter_type = "e1000e"
  }

  # Storage
  # Drive 0 (C)
  disk {
    label            = "disk0"
    unit_number      = 0
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size
    eagerly_scrub    = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.eagerly_scrub
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned
  }

  # Drive 1 (D)
  disk {
    label            = "disk1"
    unit_number      = 1
    size             = var.system_disk1_size
    eagerly_scrub    = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.1.eagerly_scrub
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.1.thin_provisioned
  }

  # Clone from template and config
  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id

    customize {
      windows_options {
        computer_name         = var.system_name
        admin_password        = random_password.password.result
        join_domain           = var.system_domain
        domain_admin_user     = var.system_domain_admin_user
        domain_admin_password = var.system_domain_admin_password
        auto_logon            = true
      }

      network_interface {
        ipv4_address    = var.system_ipv4_address
        ipv4_netmask    = var.system_ipv4_netmask
        dns_server_list = var.system_dns_server_list
      }

      ipv4_gateway = var.system_ipv4_gateway
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer largely depends on whether those VMs going to be managed as a group or individually?

If individually, then each VM would need their own terraform configuration file.

If you're managing them as a group (eg. if one VM changes, they all need to change), then you could use a [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) as part of the resource block. However, as you pointed out, that would not impact the data blocks. Therefore, I would look into Terraform modules and turning that configuration into a module to help make it a little more reusable regardless of how you're looking to manage those VM resources. There's a Learn guide to help with the process of creating and referencing a module too: [Module Overview](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/module?in=terraform/modules)

Comment: what about using the count meta-argument? - https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html